# How to briefly turn an entire sprite another color in Unity?

Tags: shaders

Let's say there's a simple Sprite, like this Umbrella:

[image]

I'd like to briefly turn the entire Sprite a different color (say, red), as a visual error message in my game.

Of course if I just change the Color of the Umbrella's Sprite Renderer to Red, then the Sprite color changes to a Purplish/Black.

I'd like to have the Sprite color turn the entire Sprite a precise shade of the Red that I input.

Obviously I could easily do this by creating red versions of all of my sprites, then temporarily swapping out the sprite.  But I'd rather avoid that if possible, as I have 60+ sprites.

After researching this, it seems like the solution might be shaders.  Is there a simple shader I could use to achieve this, that doesn't put a heavy load on CPU?  I'm looking to deploy my game to mobile devices, so I'm hoping for a mobile-friendly solution.  If there isn't a simple shader, then I'll just use the "create a plain red version of every sprite" approach since I know that's computationally cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Go to the [Unity Download Archive](https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive) and navigate to the version you're using. Hit the drop-down and download the built-in shaders for that version.

[image: Downloading built-in shaders]

**Step 2:** Make a copy of the default sprite shader found under `DefaultResourcesExtra/Sprites-Default.shader` in that download.

**Step 3:** Modify the shader like so - first give it a customized name at the top:

```
Shader "Sprites/ColorLerp"
{
```

Then replace the fragment shader function with a custom one:

```
    Pass
    {
    CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex SpriteVert
        #pragma fragment ColorLerpFrag // Use our version instead of the default.
        #pragma target 2.0
        #pragma multi_compile_instancing
        #pragma multi_compile_local _ PIXELSNAP_ON
        #pragma multi_compile _ ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
        #include "UnitySprites.cginc"


        fixed4 ColorLerpFrag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
        {
            // Sample sprite texture.
            fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord);
            // Blend toward sprite component color depending on its alpha.
            c.rgb = lerp(IN.color.rgb, c.rgb, IN.color.a);
            // Pre-multiply alpha to work with the blending function.
            c.rgb *= c.a;
            return c;
        }
    ENDCG
    }
```

This replaces the normal multiplicative tint behaviour with one where the sprite texture blends to a solid colour based on the colour swatch you set in the `SpriteRenderer` component. When that swatch has 100% alpha, you see the normal sprite texture unmodified. At 0% alpha, you see the swatch colour, regardless of what's in the texture (but the texture's alpha is still used to control the opacity and keep the shape's silhouette).

Slap this on a material, and use this material on sprites that need this effect. When you want a sprite to change to a red colour, set `spriteRenderer.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0);`, then when you want to change it back, `spriteRenderer.color = Color.white;`

In terms of cost, this adds one scalar addition and one vector fused multiply-add to the default shader - nothing significant, so you probably won't notice any difference in throughput.

Comment: This works wonderfully - thank you so much!  Only problem I experienced is that I use the Animator to animate the transparency of the Sprite Color, so it is freezing the A value and not letting me set it in code.  I may have to vary the transparency of the Sprite Color in code instead of using the Animator...

Comment: I resolved this by turning off the Animator component, and then changing the Material and Sprite.  Then I waited for a split second, changed the Materials and Sprite back... and then turned the Animator component back on.