# Is it possible to add light/fire effects to the sprite used in the UI (Using Unity 2021.3.25f1

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Essentially I want to light all orange areas

Tried changing the render mode on the canvas and rearranging the Image object in the canvas - nothing worked. [image]

Comment: Is that a single image or do you have the source of that image seperated in different layers?

Comment: yeah I have the source, I removed the background in Gimp, added the alpha-channel

Comment: [You can write your own custom sprite shader by modifying the default as I show here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/205193/39518). Though for an effect like this you might prefer to keep the base sprite unchanged, then layer on a glow/fire effect with another sprite in front of it, using additive blending.

Comment: Does it mean I have to manually mask the orange pixels in gimp?

Comment: I'm rather specifically interested in adding a particle effect, like a glow